# Can't center navigation menu

Tags: html, css

I can't seem to center the text in my navigation menu.

Below is the code snippet.

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: black;
  text-align: center;
}

li {
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: #FDE635;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: black;
}

.active {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#faq">FAQ</a></li>
  <li><a href="#download">Download</a></li>
</ul>
```

All the text in the menu bar are left-aligned, when I want them to be centered.  Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You are using `float: left` on your `li` elements and floating elements are not affected by alignment, remove that and leave only the `display: inline-block`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try to add some css-flex properties to your list :

```
ul {
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In conjunction with that comment from arieljuod, all you'd need is a container that will center your list which can be easily done using flexbox.

```css
.d-flex {
  display: flex;
}

.flex-center {
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.nav > ul {
  list-style: none;
}

.nav > ul > li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px;
}

.nav > ul > li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav d-flex flex-center">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Nav Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Nav Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Nav Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Nav Link</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Also, here's a [pen](https://codepen.io/RaysOfTheSun/pen/PVNLQm) :)

Answer (score 0):

Remove `float:left` from `li` and menu will center

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: black;
  text-align: center;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: #FDE635;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: black;
}

.active {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#faq">FAQ</a></li>
  <li><a href="#download">Download</a></li>
</ul>
```